# How to pass value using variable in res.setHeader express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Trying to send file on the frontend with its name and extension.

```
var fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
res.setHeader("Content-disposition", `attachment; filename=${fileName}`);
fileReadStream.pipe(res);
```

On the frontend, getting
**ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION**

How can I send the file name with its extension to download on the frontend?

Comment: When you comment out the .setHeader() line, what do you get in the browser? Also, just use this: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile (this is the reason for the error I guess, express is already taking care of everything, so you'll get two content disposition headers)

Comment: @ChrisG, without setting header, file is downloading with name "download" without extension. And need to send file using stream and with original name, so using stream.

Comment: The error message suggests that you are setting multiple content-disposition headers. Use the Network tab in your browser's developer tools to check. Then trace through all your code to track down where you are adding another one (since I can't see this piece of code doing that by itself).

Comment: Why do you need to send it using a stream? Why not simply use `res.sendFile(filePath);`? Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the header like this

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"
```

In your case you should do it like below

```js
var fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
res.setHeader(`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=${fileName}`);
fileReadStream.pipe(res);
```

Comment: Based on the error OP is getting, it clearly works the way they do it. Also, the fact that they're doing it is creating the problem, so not sure how doing the wrong thing the "right" way is going to fix it?

Comment: getting this in log:      TypeError [ERR_INVALID_HTTP_TOKEN]: Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Atif Aslam, Tajdar-e-Haram, Coke Studio Season 8, Episode 1._Full-HD.mp4"]

Comment: In my project, I am doing the same thing and it's working. So it should work for him too.

Comment: See [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestsetheadername-value). The `setHeader` method takes **two** arguments (a header name and a header value). Your recommendation to change that to a single argument is wrong. Perhaps you are confusing it with PHP's `header` function which only takes a single argument.